# sorl thumbnails not loading images

Tags: python, django, sorl-thumbnail

I am having trouble getting thumbnails working with sorl.thumbnails.
I am getting no errors.

What I have done:

settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = {
...
'sorl.thumbnail',
}  

THUMBNAIL_DEBUG = True
...
```

models.py

```
...
from sorl.thumbnail import ImageField
...
class Upload(models.Model):
    article = models.ForeignKey(Article, related_name="uploads")
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_image_path, blank=True)
```

template

```
{% extends 'layouts/base.html' %}
{% block title %}Home - {{ block.super }}{% endblock %}
{% load staticfiles %}
{% load thumbnail %}

{% block content %}
<section class="main clearfix">
{% for article in articles %}
  <div class="work">

    <a href="{% url 'article_detail' slug=article.slug %}">
      {% for upload in article.uploads.all %}
      {% thumbnail article.image "200x200" as im %}
        <img src="{{ im.url }}" width="{{ im.width }}" height="{{ im.height }}"class="media" alt=""/>
      {% endthumbnail %}
      {% endfor %}

    <div class="caption">
      <div class="work_title">
        <h1>{{ article.name }}</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
    </a>
  </div>

{% endfor %}
</section><!-- end main -->
{% endblock %}
```

views.py

```
...
def index(request):
    articles = Article.objects.all().order_by('-featured')
    return render(request, 'index.html', {
        'articles': articles,
    })

def article_detail(request, slug):
    #grab the object
    article = Article.objects.get(slug=slug)

    #grab all object Images
    uploads = article.uploads.all()
    # pass to the template
    return render(request, 'articles/article_detail.html', {
        'article': article,
        'uploads': uploads,
    })
...
```

urls.py

```
...
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += [
    url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$','django.views.static.serve', {
        'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT,
        }),
    ]
...
```

I have been stuck on this for a while. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Check the following:

- does `{{ article.image.url }}` output anything?
- does `{{ im.url }}` output anything?
- is any thumnail created when you load the page? Check your media folder.
- are you sure `THUMBNAIL_DEBUG` is `True`?

  - ./manage.py shell
  - from django.conf import settings
  - print settings.THUMBNAIL_DEBUG
- `pip freeze` => double check the doc for the version you're using

---

Also, you have an optional image:

```
image = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_image_path, blank=True)
```

so you probably want to check if there is an image:

```
{% if article.image %} 
   THE THUMBNAIL 
{% else %} 
   A PLACEHOLDER?  
{% endif %}
```

Comment: does {{ article.image.url }} output anything? - No, not even a blank image icon.

does {{ im.url }} output anything? - No, not even a blank image icon.

No thumbnails are created in media.

THUMBNAIL_DEBUG is true

pilkit==1.1.13
Pillow==3.0.0
sorl-thumbnail==12.3

Used the condition in the template still got nothing back.

Any other idea?

Comment: I edited the post. The thumbnails are supposed to be generated from index using the images from article_detail

Answer (score 0):

Ah, the image is on your `Upload` model !

Replace:

```
{% thumbnail article.image "200x200" as im %}
```

With:

```
{% thumbnail upload.image "200x200" as im %}
```

---

My other answer stay true though. You need to check if there is an image:

```
{% if upload.image %}
```

Comment: That makes sense. Still no luck here. I have added the static files url to the post. I am thinking it may be an issue with finding the images as the {% else %} condition is loading my <p> placeholder.

Comment: If you're placeholder is loading, it means that `upload` does not have an image. It has nothing to do with the `static` path as the files uploaded by users are under the `media` path.